# does typescript compiler has @inline function option ?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
 //ts code
function div(props?: { id?: String; style?: any }) {
      return function(...children: ReactNode[]) {
        return createElement("div", props, ...children);
      };
    }
const d = div({ id: "hello" })("welcome to TS");
```

Generated JS code

```
function div(props) {
    return function () {
        var children = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            children[_i] = arguments[_i];
        }
        return createElement("div",props,...);
    };
}
var d = div({ id: "hello" })("welcome to TS");
```

// Trying to achieve

```
var d = createElement("div",{ id: "hello" },"welcome to TS")
```

does typescript support @inline functions ? if not whats the best way achieve similar ..

Comment: Nope, no support for inline functions in Typescript, you should trust the JS runtime to do the optimizing, or hand code it the way you want.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, read ["Automatic Inlining in JavaScript Engines"](https://ariya.io/2013/04/automatic-inlining-in-javascript-engines) --- If you have code that is so critical you want to hand-optimize such details you should check out WASM (WebAssembly), this is exactly one of its use cases ([Youtube: Dan Callahan: Practical WebAssembly | JSConf Budapest 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bac0dGQbUto) - skip the first 15 minutes).

Comment: thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does typescript support @inline functions ?

No.

> if not whats the best way achieve similar

You will have to write a tool yourself. I would just not worry about it.

## Make the tool yourself

Use the TypeScript compiler to find references to functions you want to inline, and then interpolate the function body to that location.

Start: Some compiler docs https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/overview

Comment: thanks for reply, can you link me to some articles/tutorials/docs how to achieve similar things..., Even though its not useful for this use case i may come across different needs in future..

Comment: Added more info for that 

Comment: Link is dead. Please update your answer.

Comment: Just tested and link is working